# 10V voltage with raspberry and arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

is there a simple way to connect the 5V pins of the Arduino and the raspberry pi in series to get 10V ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The pins are already all connected in parallel, you can't change that.

Comment: OK thx, so I guess the only way to get a higher voltage from an arduino or a raspberry is to use a boost converter, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Do you want to have a 10 V power supply, or do you just want to switch a 10 V device on and off?

Comment: @CaptainCoding7 I highly recommend using a transistor with an external battery. You can use the Arduino to "toggle" the transistor to output the 10v from the battery.

Comment: I suppose he could take one pin from each device and connect them in series?

Comment: Yes I'm tring to have a 10V power supply @Hearth

Comment: Ok @KingDuken I will do this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could **just theoretically** connect +5V pin from Arduino to Raspberry 0V pin, and so you could obtain 10V when probing +5V pin of Raspberry to 0V pin of Arduino.

But **DON'T DO IT.**

Besides of getting two points that can be measured as 10v potential with your multimeter, this setting will be of no utility at all.

You can't connect Arduino to Rpi (first because Rpi uses 3.3V logic, second because what Arduino thinks as "digital 1", Rpi would see as digital 0.

This is a really nonsense and there are a dozen practical reasons for not doing this in a real world situation. There are other ways of doing whatever you want to do.

Comment: ok thanks @mguima, I didn't see your answer one month ago !